# meteor velocity force build option

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

Is there an option to force build the Velocity 'mirror' code when velocity runs each time ?

Sometimes my code changes do not propagate to the 'mirror' app being tested ( is 'mirror' the appropriate term here ? ).

UPDATE : 
so I just noticed the steps to replicate include

1. create new file
2. reference objects in the new file from existing code

upon creating a new file it seems I need to stop the app and restart it for the Velocity 'mirror' to rebuild and pick up the change.  Which is not that big of a deal.  Is this expected behavior for velocity?

i'm on a mac, using mike:mocha

thanks

Comment: This is a bug and not expected behavior. Which version of mike:mocha are you using?

Comment: mike:mocha@0.5.2  , is it possible it's a permissions issue?  maybe I haven't setup my environment correctly to be able to write those 'mirror' files ?  I've had all sorts of problems with npm packages in my meteor apps due to permissions.  I'm on mac os 10.9.5.  Usually I 'sudo' everything blindly and hope it works.  thanks.